# assembler ELF program header overlap

Tags: assembly, elf

I am looking at a demo software i made and after inspecting program header with `readelf` i saw that `NOTE` header is overlaping with `LOAD` header.

```
readelf -l test

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400144
There are 4 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8  R E    200000
  NOTE           0x0000000000000120 0x0000000000400120 0x0000000000400120
                 0x0000000000000024 0x0000000000000024  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000178 0x0000000000400178 0x0000000000400178
                 0x0000000000000014 0x0000000000000014  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RWE    8
```

how can this be possible ?

`LOAD` offset start at 0x00000..00 and has a size of 0x00...1c8 and `NOTE` start at offset 0x000..120 . It sould start at offset 0x000..1c9

Thanks

Comment: There is no problem with overlapping headers. Actually only `LOAD` is mapped into memory, but if it happens to contain other segments (as per `Offset` and `FileSiz`) that means those segments are also accessible in memory.

Comment: so it doesn't matter if it overlaps ... i didn't know that , if so basically the `NOTE` program header is also in memory right ?

Comment: Yes, it's also in memory as per the appropriate `LOAD` segment.